# There are no simple groups of order $480$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

Before this writing the smallest order for which the nonexistence of simple groups of that order is not explicitly demonstrated on this site is 480; this self-answered question aims to fill that gap. (See [Prove there are no simple groups of even order $<500$ except orders $2$, $60$, $168$, and $360$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433417/prove-there-are-no-simple-groups-of-even-order-500-except-orders-2-60/3433540), the sole answer of which describes an outline for proving the titular statement but does not describe how to establish the claim for order $480$. In particular, this question-answer pair completes that outline in the sense that all cases not explicitly resolved therein are covered by other, linked answers on this site.) Other answers are, of course, welcome.

> How does one show that there are no simple groups of order $480$?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $G$ is a simple group of order $480 = 2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

Since $G$ is simple, if it has a proper subgroup of index $k$, then $G$ embeds into $S_k$; as $480 \not\mid |S_k|$ for $k \leq 7$, any proper subgroup of $G$ has index $\geq 8$.$^*$ Sylow's Third Theorem then gives that the count $n_2 := |\operatorname{Syl}_2(G)|$ satisfies $n_2 \mid 15$ and $n_2 = |P : N_G(P)| \geq 8$ (for any, equivalently, every $P \in \operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$), leaving only the possibility$$n_2 = 15 .$$

Now consider the conjugation action of $P \in \operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$ on $\operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$. Since $N_P(Q) = P \cap Q$ (see, e.g., [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067039/sylow-subgroups-and-conjugation)), and the size of the $P$-orbit of any $Q \in \operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$ is $|P \cdot Q| = |P : N_P(Q)| = |P : P \cap Q|$. So, the action has $1$ fixed point ($P$ itself), and it partitions the set $\operatorname{Syl}_2(G) \setminus \{P\}$ of the remaining $14$ Sylow $2$-subgroups into orbits whose sizes are factors of $|P| = 2^5$ larger than $1$.

Since $2^2 \not\mid 14$, there is at least $1$ orbit of length $2$, hence some $R \in \operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$ such that $|P : P \cap R| = 2$; denote $T := P \cap R$. In particular, $T$ has index $2$ in both $P$ and $R$ and hence is normal in both. Since $N_G(T)$ contains both $P$ and $R$, $|N_G(T)| \geq 2^5 \cdot 3 = 96$, and hence $[G : N_G(T)] \leq \frac{480}{96} = 5$. Now, either $N_G(T) = G$, so that $T \trianglelefteq G$, which contradicts the simplicity of $G$, or $N_G(T)$ is a proper subgroup of index $\leq 5$, which contradicts our observation that every proper subgroup of $G$ must have index $\geq 8$.

$\mathbf{{}^*}$**Remark** In fact, if $G$ embeds in $S_k$, it must embed in $A_k$; otherwise $G \cap A_k$ would be an index-$2$---hence normal---subgroup of $G$, a contradiction. Moreover, Conway et al.'s *ATLAS of Simple Groups* shows that $A_8$ has no subgroups of order $480$, so in fact any proper subgroup of $G$ would have to have index $\geq 10$.

Comment: I don’t see why $\vert N_G(T) \vert \geq 64$.  Could you please explain that conclusion?  Is it because $2^5 \mid \vert N_G(T) \vert$ and also some odd prime $p \mid \vert N_G(T) \vert$ (which implies $\vert N_G(T) \vert \geq 96$)?

Comment: It comes from looking at the largest possible overlaps of the Sylow-$2$ subgroups. Since $P, P'$ have a maximum intersection of size $2^4$, $P \cup P' \subset N_G(T)$ has at least $|P| + |P'| - |P \cap P| \geq 32 + 32 - 16 = 48$ elements. Now consider the third Sylow-$2$ subgroup of $N_G(T)$. (In fact, for this argument it's enough to see that $N_G(T)$ has $> \frac{|G|}{8} = 60$ elements.) But your observation is cleaner---I'll fold it into my answer. Thanks!

Comment: At the start of your argument, $16$ distinct $5$-Sylow subgroups must account for $16 \cdot (5-1)=64$ elements of order $5$, not just $48$ such elements.  The elements of the $2$-Sylow subgroups don't necessarily have order $2$, but they do have order that's a power of $2$, and that's good enough for your argument.

Comment: You're right, thank you; I've fixed the issue. Of course, that adjustment does not affect the conclusion!

Comment: Why is it necessarily the case that $P$ normalizes $T$?  It's not obvious to me that $T \trianglelefteq P$, and this point (unlike the earlier nits) is essential to your argument.

Comment: @RobertShore Hm, that conclusion needn't follow in general. It's sufficient to show that $P, P'$ are both of index $2$ (i.e., $|P \cap P'| = 2^4$), and that turns out to be true in this case as a consequence of the fact that $n_p \not\cong 1 \pmod{p^2}$ for $p = 2$. (That implication in turn follows from analyzing the conjugation action of $P$ on $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$.) But I was hoping to avoid using that lemma. I'll see if I can find another way to fix the gap, perhaps with a counting argument. Thanks for your close reading!

Comment: (Any suggestions you have are also welcome.)

Comment: (The noncongruence in my comment at 03:03Z should read $n_p \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$.)

Comment: In the conjugation action of $P$ on the set of $15$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, there must be an orbit of length $2$, so we there is another Sylow $2$-subgroup $P'$ with $|P \cap P'|=8$. Now the normalizer in $G$ of $P \cap P'$ contains $P$ and $p'$, so it has order at least $3 \cdot 2^5$, which is is too big.

Comment: @DerekHolt Your comment took me a bit to unpack, but I see now that it's a cleaner way of appealing to the ideas behind the lemma I mentioned above, and it helped clarify my thinking about the issue. Thanks for the especially helpful comment!